# Troubleshooting UDP Multicast issue

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, multicast, udpclient

I am trying to broadcast a UDP datagram to a multicast address on the local network.
This works perfectly fine across dozens of machines, except for one specific machine.
 This particular machine **is able** to receive datagrams from the multicast address, but is not able to send messages.

This is the code I am using:

```
using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient())
{
    client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, remoteEP);
    client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    client.Client.Close();
}
```

where `remoteEP` is the IP address and port of the multicast group, and `bytes` is valid data.

- There is no exception being raised, the message simply is not delivered.
- The message **is** received in the loopback on the same machine from `127.0.0.1`.
- The message is **not** shown in Wireshark outgoing traffic.
- The machine is the only one in the network which is running Windows 8.
- The Windows firewall is disabled.
- The machine is in the same subnet as the listening machines.
- There is only one active network interface on this machine.
- I've tried:

  - `client.BroadcastEnabled = true;`.
  - Joining the multicast group on the client side.
  - using `BeginSend` instead of `Send`.

Any ideas for debugging are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, after searching for a solution all day, I find it 2 minutes after posting an SO question.

The method in [this](http://windowsasusual.blogspot.ru/2013/01/socket-option-multicast-interface.html) article helped. I guess there were network interfaces I was not aware of.

This is the revised code:

```
using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient())
{
    NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
    {
        IPInterfaceProperties ip_properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
        if (adapter.GetIPProperties().MulticastAddresses.Count == 0)
            continue; // most of VPN adapters will be skipped
        if (!adapter.SupportsMulticast)
            continue; // multicast is meaningless for this type of connection
        if (OperationalStatus.Up != adapter.OperationalStatus)
            continue; // this adapter is off or not connected
        IPv4InterfaceProperties p = adapter.GetIPProperties().GetIPv4Properties();
        if (null == p)
            continue; // IPv4 is not configured on this adapter
        client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastInterface, (int)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(p.Index));
        break;
    }

    client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, remoteEP);
    client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    client.Client.Close();
}
```